# if ANY $_POST equals another $_POST die('error');?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to get this form to:

if any $_POST vars equals any other of the $_POST vars throw an error.

if it was just a few it wouldnt be an issue but I have about 20 or so
so if i wanted to do it I would have to go like

```
    <?php 
    if($_POST['input1']==$_POST['input2'] || $_POST['input1']==$_POST['input3']){
die('whatever');
}

    ?>
```

But that's not good coding (and it would take forever)
I thought about arrays and different ways...

but I am brain dead atm so I thought I could get some help..
thanks in advance

ps it would be nice to do it in PHP (server side) but Jquery is always an option.

Comment: Btw, die('some screwed up message') is NOT the way to handle errors.

Comment: @Hanse still better than //TODO: fix me

Comment: I was only using die as an example... I rarely use die.

Comment: @Hanse: What's your opinion on handling error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function testPost(){
foreach ($_POST as $keya=>$vala){
    foreach($_POST as $keyb=>$valb){
        if ($keya==$keyb){
            continue;
        } else {
            if ($vala == $valb){
                 return FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
}
return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Delete duplicate values with [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) and check if it still equals to your array:

```
if($_POST != array_unique($_POST))
    die("...");
```

Comment: I will give a warning, the function does cast each element as a string before doing a === operation. This will only be good for post variables , but you might get a few problems if you wander into other arrays with casted types or special formatting.

Comment: ok works great... only 1 problem.... I forgot that SOME can be the same..... any suggestions??... would a $post_a=$_POST['a']; unset($_POST['a']); and then set it back after the check work??

Comment: You can still do an `array_diff($_POST, array_unique($_POST))` and check duplicate keys.

Comment: Again, do `$duplicatesArray = array_keys (array_diff($_POST, array_unique($_POST)))` check these values, if they're on your blacklist, then you call the die() method.

Answer (score 2):

if ($_POST == [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)($_POST)) {}

Comment: What does `[array_unique][1]($_POST)` do?  Haven't seen that syntax.

Comment: Oh, I see why the post is written as `[array_unique][1]($_POST)`.

The `[array_unique][1]` is supposed to be a link, but Sarfraz edited the post and messed up the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

This is only an answer to [zebediah49's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578305/if-any-post-equals-another-post-dieerror/3578350#3578350). A more effective implementation would be:

```
$post = array_value($_POST);
$count = count($post);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $count; ++$j) {
        if ($post[$i] == $post[$j]) {
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

This saves all the multiple checks. So it results in O(2*n) instead of O(n^2) (if I got that O stuff right). Though I don't know how much this is slowed down by the additional `array_values`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$postValues = array_values($_POST);

if (array_unique($postValues)) != $postValues) {
    die('error!');
}
```

not so good, but

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you have to do it in a double-loop; while it's O(n^2), it'll not be problematic in practice

```
foreach($_POST as $keya=>$vala) {
    foreach($_POST as $keyb => $valb) {
        if($vala == $valb && $keya != $keyb) {
            die('whatever');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$count_array = array_count_values($_POST);
foreach($_POST as $post) {
  if($count_array[$post] >1 ) {
    die();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my final code... so basically i'm putting the ones I want into an array

credits will go to @akellehe because his was the closest to my end result....

works great

```
$titles=array();
        $num=1;
        while($num!=15){
        $set1='title'.$num;
        $set2=$_REQUEST["title$num"];
        $titles[$set1]=$set2;
        unset($set1);
        unset($set2);
        $num+=1;
        }
        foreach($titles as $d => $p){
            foreach($titles as $e =>$q){
            if($p==$q && $d!=$e){
            if(!empty($p)){
            $_SESSION['error']='Duplicates not allowed!';
            }
            }
            }
        }
```